# Troubles with three-columns html

Tags: html, multiple-columns

I have a problem with a three columns display. I have white space between two columns.
It's hard to explain with words, so here is a screen :

[image]

Each big category (excavators, loaders...) is an UL. Each in `float:left` 
I would like to remove the white space between Loaders and Motor grader or between Scraper and Telescopic forklift...

Here is the generated HTML

```
<div class="right_list">
                <ul class="group_list">
        <li><a class="titre_cat" href="xxx" title="Excavators">Excavators (588)</a></li>

                                            <li><a class="sous_cat" href="xxx" title="Dragline Excavators ">Dragline Excavators  (1)</a></li>
                                <li><a class="sous_cat" href="xxx" title="Track excavators ">Track excavators  (239)</a></li>
                                <li><a class="sous_cat" href="xxx" title="Wheel excavator">Wheel excavator (111)</a></li>
                                <li><a class="sous_cat" href="xxx" title="Industrial excavators">Industrial excavators (3)</a></li>
                                <li><a class="sous_cat" href="xxx" title="Excavators accesories">Excavators accesories (13)</a></li>
                                <li><a class="sous_cat" href="xxx" title="Mini digger ">Mini digger  (221)</a></li>
                                </ul>
[... and more and more ...]
</div>
```

Here are the CSS applied :

```
.right_list {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 7px;
    width: 756px;
}

.group_list {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 5px 0;
    width: 242px;
}
```

Here is what I want :

[image]

Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create 3 columns first, then put your divs into those columns. The column itself should be also a `div`.

```
<div class="col">
  <div class="right_list"></div>
  <div class="right_list"></div>
  <div class="right_list"></div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="right_list"></div>
  <div class="right_list"></div>
  <div class="right_list"></div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="right_list"></div>
  <div class="right_list"></div>
  <div class="right_list"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: My categories are generated dynamically. Using float is easier for me. If I create first 3 columns, then I split my result in 3 and then I display... don' tyou think there is a trick in CSS for handle that white space ?

Else... I do three column first XD

Comment: I don't know about such a trick. But in your code, where you build the list, you can build 3 lists in a paralell way, and split the divs depending on the item counter modulo 3. You can try that you don't set the `height` for your div, but I suppose it will just be ugly.